# Problems with charset conversion when uploading files using File Browser in Oracle Apex 22

Tags: special-characters, apex, file-browser, charset

I'm uploading a text file using "File Browser" field that by default, is storing the content in a BLOB column of the apex_application_temp_files table.

The text file has some special characteres like "çéãôáó"

but the special char has not been considered, instead they has been replaced by "�" char, example: Importa�s

I tried change my browser language, also executed the command below, but still having same issue.

```
BEGIN
    APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_LANG( P_LANG => 'pt-br');
    APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_TERRITORY( P_TERRITORY => 'BRAZIL');
END;
```

Does anybody have a clue?

Any help is welcome.

Thanks a lot.